# 2008 Honda Rebel 250 idle problem

Tags: honda, motorcycle, carburetor, idle

I have a Honda Rebel and it's been running great for the last year. It does have about 8000 miles on it but I haven't had any serious issues.

Lately, I noticed the idle was higher than normal. It seems to be idling very high in all gears. I can't figure out why this happened all of the sudden. Before I take it in to the Honda dealer, I wanted to get an idea of why this might be happening.

Comment: Just curious... do you start it with the choke closed? Do you open it up after the engine warms up? Maybe its a defective choke? Just a thought.

Comment: Does the idle ever fall quickly after idling high,then stall or almost stall when the idle drops?